# Global Estimates for Quantile Regression

Tags: feature-selection, regression-coefficients, quantile-regression

Quantile regression (QR) provides information at each quantile of interest (e.g., .1, .2 ... .8, .9), but to compare QR results with those from an ordinary least squares regression, you'd need to estimate global metrics (e.g., beta coefficients). I found one approach, cited in [Sayedh, Munir, & Habeebullah (2014)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e470/5d25f7fb959102dce39f126f66a85537ad87.pdf), called the Amalgamated Quantile Regression, but cannot seem to find  information on the method anywhere, nor direction for how to conduct the analysis. Is there another approach that can be used to calculate global estimates (e.g., beta coefficients) for quantile regression? Or, is anyone familiar with the Amalgamated Quantile Regression?

In general, this would come in handy for variable selection and weighting when building composites based on quantile regression results.

Comment: I have not heard of AQR before, but perhaps composite quantile regression is relevant here? See Koenker ["Quantile Regression"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantile-regression/C18AE7BCF3EC43C16937390D44A328B1) (2005) or [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378375818302568) for some further development.

Comment: Thanks, Richard -- I'll take a look!